# LINQ query expression vs using IEnumerable.Where and IEnumerable.Select

Tags: python, c#, linq, generator, ienumerable

I'm coming to C# from Python where we have generator comprehensions such as

```
nums = range(2, 10)
evenSquares = (num*num for num in nums if num % 2 == 0)
for evenSquare in evenSquares:
  print(evenSquare)
```

The above would print

```
4
16
36
64
```

I was looking for a C# equivalent or near-equivalent to Python's generator comprehension and found two candidates

- LINQ query expressions
- Using `IEnumerable` query methods (e.g. `Where` and `Select`).

The above Python snippet could be done in C# as either

```
// LINQ query expression
IEnumerable<int> nums = Enumerable.Range(2, 8);
IEnumerable<int> evenSquares =
    from num in nums
    where num % 2 == 0
    select num*num;
```

or

```
// Using IEnumerable.Where and IEnumerable.Select
IEnumerable<int> nums = Enumerable.Range(2, 8);
IEnumerable<int> evenSquares =
    nums.Where(num => num % 2 == 0).Select(num*num);
```

and in either case

```
foreach (int evenSquare in evenSquares) {
    Console.WriteLine(evenSquare);
}
```

would also print

```
4
16
36
64
```

So I was wondering which of the two

- LINQ query expression, or
- Using IEnumerable.Where and IEnumerable.Select

is preferred and why.

---

AFAIK, like Python generator comprehensions which are evaluated lazily, LINQ query expressions and IEnumerable.Where and IEnumerable.Select are also evaluated lazily (the C# docs call it **deferred execution**, but I'm guessing it's the same as lazy evaluation, right?)

Comment: Which is preferred? Well it depends on what you need, but the code you wrote is effectively the same thing expressed in two different ways.

Comment: You mean Query syntax and Method chain syntax? Query syntax is syntax sugar for writing complex queries with joins  and, actually, C# compiler transfers Query syntax to Method chain syntax. So there no difference.

Comment: To be a little nitpicking: It's `Enumerable.Where` and `Enumerable.Select` by the way not **I**_Enumerable_. `System.Linq.Enumerable` is a static class that hosts all standard Linq extension methods, like Where, Select, Any, First etc ...
System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<T> is the mother of all collections, so to speak, And is usually the type of the first parameter of these methods.